# ngdocs:Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, grunt-ngdocs

Whenever we run gulp/grunt task using ngdocs npm module docs folder is generated, if we click on index.html in console it throws the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at Gb (angular.js:10638)
at Me.$get (angular.js:11465)
at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4219)
at angular.js:4037
at d (angular.js:4178)
at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4210)
at angular.js:4037
at d (angular.js:4178)
at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4210)
at angular.js:6547
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get this error because chrome, for security reasons doesn't allow loading things from file system, so the solution is to run server(i.e http-server) in our directory and then view the files at `localhost:portnumber`